# Related to Voice Recognition Google API android

Tags: android, listview, voice-recognition

Voice Recognition API produces a list of suggestions after listening a voice.I wanted to know , does the most probable suggestion always comes on the top?or it is just random..
I need this to make calculations for determining accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u using

```
new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
```

and

```
data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

will always sorts best matches first

Yes

Comment: Yes I am using the same .Thanks for the answer :)